# Is there an API to intract with windows command prompt?

Tags: c#

There is a situation, wherein I need to continously read, write and process some things according to the output received from command prompt window. For example, if command window is looking for an input, I need to show a messagebox to the user. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: A message box isn't a very good way to allow the user to enter input.  Not much beyond yes/no/cancel.  This question has a common problem, it doesn't explain at all why this is needed.  So it is impossible to guess what you really need.

Comment: You should look into PowerShell, which has a full API

Comment: @JohnSaunders that depends on what OP is trying to achieve, and why...

Comment: He should look at it, and decide.

Answer (score 3):

Through the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process.aspx) object you can redirect standard input and output.

So you would do something like the following...

```
        var proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\YourExeGoesHere.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        proc.Start();

        var thisComesFromTheProcess = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("this goes to the process");
```

You may want to look at the [Process.OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) event to be notified when output data is written but this should get you on the right track and there are other SO posts that cover the OutputDataReceived event.

Answer (score 1):

I would have the command line application launch a WPF executable.

Have the WPF opens a socket/web api host etc. to listen for additional command.

When the command line needs input from the user, have it run a batch, which submits a request to the WPF application, no unlike a [telnet session](http://www.360doc.com/content/08/0501/12/41237_1227701.shtml). You can make this call asynchronous or wait for response accordingly.

The WPF can then opens a notification, ask for user input. User enter an argument, and submits it back to the command line above that initiates the connection, allowing your batch file to continue processing.

Alternatively if you can use Powershell, instead of a standard CommandLine, [this](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2012/03/16/showing-msgbox.aspx) might be of use. You can even open file dialog like [this](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2013/02/14/using-open-file-dialogs.aspx).

Those are your options I could think of, but yeah it's gonna be a PITA, so good luck to you.